# How should I go about converting my Windows Phone App to a Silverlight Web App?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'd like to convert my Windows Phone app to a silverlight web app, while keeping most of the code intact (so I don't have to maintain 2 different code bases). I've never built a Silverlight website before so I'd like to get some advise on how I should go about doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add more about the current structure of the application. A lot depends on that.

Comment: The standard practice is to move as much code as you can into [portable class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) which can be shared between different application types.

Answer (score 3):

Use the MVVM pattern and have device specific views. Take a look at MVVM light wich is a good framework for MVVM.